# How let the Liquid Domain disappear, but keep the mesh of the fluid visible?

Tags: mesh, fluid-simulation

I have a problem with the Fluids. I have render water around 1000 frames for a half day now. But the whole animation is 4780 frames long. After the 1000 Frames i don't need more moving Water, but i still need the water mesh in background. Sadly ever new render after 1000 frames have now a big fat cube in the view.

I know i can deactivate the Domain with "Show in Renders". Sadly this deactivate the water mesh from the last frame, too. Is there a way to keep the mesh, but make the domain invisible? Can i somehow copy the last mesh, deactivate domain after frame 1000 and use the mesh for the next 3780 frames as an object?

Comment: You can apply the fluid at the last frame at the modifiers tab. Then "Save As" the file, reload the unapplied one and "Append" the mesh of the last frame of the simulation from the new file. Then swap the visibility of the objects at the last simulated frame.